# Finding general solution based on system of equation

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

My question is from a [homework set](https://math.berkeley.edu/%7Emgu/MA54/HWset7.pdf) I found: In $\mathbb{R}^4$, and given 3 orthonormal vectors $u_1, u_2, u_3$, can we find a fourth vector $u_4$ such that all 4 vectors are orthonormal?

Given are $u_1 = [\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}], u_2 = [\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}, -\frac{1}{2}, -\frac{1}{2}], u_3 = [\frac{1}{2}, -\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}, -\frac{1}{2}]$

Let $u_4 = [a, b, c, d]$. Then the dot product of $u_4$ with any of the other vectors needs to be $0$. So we can encode this in the following system of equations:

$$
\frac{1}{2}a + \frac{1}{2}b + \frac{1}{2}c + \frac{1}{2}d = 0 \\
\frac{1}{2}a + \frac{1}{2}b - \frac{1}{2}c - \frac{1}{2}d = 0 \\ 
\frac{1}{2}a - \frac{1}{2}b + \frac{1}{2}c - \frac{1}{2}d = 0 
$$

Row-reducing this in matrix form gave me the following solutions:

$$
a+b+c+d = 0 \\
b - c = 0
$$

Now how to derive a general solution from here?

In the homework set they mention that the general solution would be $u_4 = [t, -t, -t, t]$ and I agree, but based on the simplified system of equations I wouldn't have been able to see that (expect that $b=c=t$, that's clear.) I think I'm missing some intermediate step to understand the given solution.

Comment: $u_1, u_2, u_3$ are linearly independent, so should be your three equations. As a consequence, you shouldn't be able to reduce them to two equations, so my guess is, something went wrong with the Gauss algorithm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The system of equations you got, is correct

$\frac{1}{2}a + \frac{1}{2}b + \frac{1}{2}c + \frac{1}{2}d = 0 \\
\frac{1}{2}a + \frac{1}{2}b - \frac{1}{2}c - \frac{1}{2}d = 0 \\ 
\frac{1}{2}a - \frac{1}{2}b + \frac{1}{2}c - \frac{1}{2}d = 0$

From here these equations are reduced (you did something wrong while row reducing the matrix equation associated with the above system of equations) to

$\begin{align*}
a+b+c+d = 0  \tag{i}\\
a+b - c -d= 0 \tag{ii}\\
a-b+c-d=0 \tag{iii}
\end{align*}$

Adding (i) and (ii), we get
$2(a+b)=0 \implies a+b=0$

Substituting $a+b=0$ in (i) we get $c+d=0$

Adding (ii) and (iii), we get
$2(a-d)=0 \implies a-d=0$

Substituting $a-d=0$ in (ii) we get $b-c=0$

Thus $a+b=0, c+d=0,a-d=0,b-c=0$ (You can get some more, but these are enough),

Taking $a=t$ gives $b=-a=-t, c=b=-t, d=a=t$

$\therefore u_4 = [a, b, c, d]=[t,-t,-t,t]$

Comment: The reduced system of equations: How you solve it?

Comment: The system of equation you showed is the same as the initial, except multiplied through by $2$.

Comment: @Max Now, can you see how i solved those equations?